# Detect which is trending based on graphs

Tags: java, graph, trend

I have multiple graphs. I have the data(count) also which is used to form that graph. Is there a way I can detect from those graphs which one is most trending. I want from multiple graphs the graph which is more trending or going upwards compared to others. Basically sort the graphs ?

Data of each graph is as follows:
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [2,5,7,9,10,13,16,18,21,22]

Comment: Can you define "trending"? Most nodes? Most edges? Node with most incoming edges? Node with greatest B-Centrality?...

Comment: Suppose I have 10 days data like 23,34,34,45,32,65,21,45,23,34. Similarly I have other data like above using which I need to know which graph is going up compared to others.

Comment: Aha, x-y graph. I thought those were graph-theory graphs (nodes & edges). So, which of those 2 graphs is trending? The second one? Assuming strictly growing graphs, would it not be enough to sort by the last y-value of each graph?